# Storage::url($h->name) not working Laravel 9

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-8, laravel-9

I can't view the picture I saved under stroge/app/public/cars Storage::url($h->name) not working but  when i write it like this  {{$h->name}} inside the p tag i see this : /storage/cars/oJxxg1uYAkl0rNPoaQcVj8ycTbpB34daKEpgVi5l.png

```
@php
     $images = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('images')->where('ilan_id',$rs->file)->get();
    @endphp
    @foreach($images as $h)
     <img id="imageharrik" width="50px" height="50px" class="normal" src="{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($h->name)}}">
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Out of interest, have you run `php artisan storage:link`? See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: You'll also want to wrap your link in tue asset()  method.

Comment: yes, I did it but not working

Comment: I try this asset()  but not working

Comment: also I edit .filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first
rm -R public/storage
and again
php artisan storage:link

this is work for me good luck :)